# Update 2 values when submiting form action

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with several fields. I enjoy all the validation built into a form, and I am forbidden from using ajax.

Here is the issue: My form has a date picker and time selector. But I have to send the values as a combination of them, i.e. 6/7/2013 05:00:00.

From the research I've done, I can't stop and concatenate those values before submitting.

How can I do this without getting involved in too much trickery?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: ...and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful for us/you?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hidden element, for this example we'll use this.

```
<input type="hidden" name="datetime" value=""/>
```

When the submit event if fired on the form, run this.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  var $form = $(this);
  $form.find('[name=datetime]').val( 
    $form.find('[name=date]').val() + ' ' + $form.find('[name=time]').val()
  );
});
```

**EDIT**

I just realized this isn't tagged jQuery so here's my best attempt with vanilla javascript assuming the fields name is "add" and there's inputs named `datetime`, `date` and `time`.

```
var add = document.forms.add;

add.onsubmit = function(e){
  add.datetime.value = add.date.value + ' ' + add.time.value;
}
```

This should definitely be handled on the server side though.

Comment: Sorry, should've tagged it JQuery as that's what I'm using. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

Have a 3rd hidden field, update the value (date + time) on change on either date or time and use that value where ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery UI Datetimepicker plugin.
its will help you to catch date and time in single field.
plz refer.

$('#selectedDateTimeWithFormat').datetimepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss' });

http://timjames.me/jquery-ui-datetimepicker-plugin

Comment: Nice component, I'll check further into it.